# How to make a stock chart in Django with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, django, json, charts, stock

I want to build a stock website with Django, and I found a Javascript library ([tickp](https://bitbucket.org/gabhijit/tickp)) to make charts, but I don't know Javascript, nor do I know how to read json data in a Django template. I use [this code](https://github.com/gurch101/StockScraper) to retrieve the stock data from Yahoo Finance.

I put these .py and .js in my folder, and my views like this:

```
from stock.stockretriever import StockRetriever

def stockretriever(request,number):
    data = StockRetriever().get_historical_info('YHOO')
    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(data),mimetype='application/json')
```

But I don't know how I should write the template, can somebody tell me?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

1. render a template with data included
2. dynamically fetch data from the server

If you go for 1. you could add something like this to your template:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var my_data = {{ json_plot_data }};
</script>
```

The template includes also the javascript code that generates the plots from the data. The view function would include the data fetching and return a context object like so:

```
def my_stock_plot_view(request, number):
    # get stock data
    json_data = simplejson.dumps(data)
    django.shortcuts.render(request, 'template.html', {'json_plot_data':json_data})
```

If you go for 2. you would need to use something like jQuery.ajax to dynamically load json data using an ajax request. That request would invoke your view, in the jQuery.ajax call you specify that the request returns JSON which automatically makes the data available as an object to Javascript. In the jQuery.ajax success handler you would pass the data to your plot function.

Comment: Thanks for your help,I can't unstand the doc of it,I don't konw how to write in html template.

Comment: I write in the html template:
            <script type="text/javascript" src="/site_media/stats.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="/site_media/tkcip.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   data = {{ hisdata }};
   plot =  window.tickp("#chart") 
   plot.read(data) 
   plot.plot() 
</script>  



                  <div id="chart" >
               
                　{{hisdata}}
                  </div>   

but nothing happen.

Comment: Take a look at the template jro suggests above. Use the body onload to  call the plot commands in the way as you do. Also check the source of the rendered page whether the data appears at the place where you write data = {{ hisdata }}. Note, in my example I'm using json_plot_data for the template variable, so you'd need to change your template code to {{ json_plot_data }}.

Comment: Thanks ,guys.:)Merry Chiristmas

Answer (score 1):

I don't have these libraries installed, but based on the [readme](https://bitbucket.org/gabhijit/tickp/src/512bf8139628/Getting-Started.txt) of the `tickp` library, you'll need the following data: `[date, open, high, low, close and optionally volume]`. The [`get_historical_info`](https://github.com/gurch101/StockScraper/blob/master/stockretriever.py#L55) function returns the columns `[Date, Open, High, Low, Close, Volume, AdjClose]`. The mismatch here is the `AdjClose`, so you'd need to strip that from the data you get from the `StockRetriever`:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from stock.stockretriever import StockRetriever

def stockretriever(request, number):
    data = StockRetriever().get_historical_info('YHOO')
    # Assuming data is returned as a list of lists
    new_data = [d[:-1] for d in data]
    return render(request, 'stock.html', { 'data': simplejson.dumps(new_data) })
```

Following along with the readme, you need something along the following lines in your template:

```
<html>
<head><script src="tickp.js"></script><script src="stats.js"></script></head>
<body onload='plot = window.tickp("#chart"); plot.read({{ data }}); plot.plot();'>
  <div id="chart"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Note that I've cut some corners with respect to possible Ajax calls or proper formatting and usage, but it should give you something to get started with. When you're missing something, please update your question with the specific issues you're having.

Comment: Thanks jro,I look the format of the data when you told me that,I found that the data return back from stockretriever is a dict,and the tickp want that is a list.so,I can't use the json format?and other question is ,new_data = [d[:-1] for d in data] can't not pass in django.

Comment: You didn't mention the format of the dict, but you'd need to convert it so that the data matches the expected format. Brief example, if your dict is `d = {'date': '2011-11-28', 'open': 5.1, ...}`, you should convert this to `[d['date'], d['open'], ...]`. Hope this helps you, if not: please post the structure of the dict.

Comment: Thanks,I have already read the data in django,but nothing show in html template.